# Open a file:// protocol with UNC paths in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, unc, file-uri

I'm trying to open a file located on a networkshare by giving the anchor tag path =
file://///servername/folder/file.docx

This works in IE8 and i'm able to open the file in word, however in Firefox nothing happens. I believe it's due to some secruity settings in Firefox. I tried about:config and turning off the checkloaduri value. But it didnt solve the problem.

Does anyone know how I can make this work in both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google brought me to the following solution page from Mozillazine:

[Mozillazine's "Links to Local Pages Don't Work"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)

Comment: Yeah I tried that, as in mention in my question, the checkloaduri method.

Comment: I think you missed the section on [2.1 Firefox 1.5, SeaMonkey 1.0 and newer](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_Issues_%3a_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work#Firefox_1.5.2C_SeaMonkey_1.0_and_newer). Have you tried adding the `capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites` settings?